# Matching elements in arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function

So basically my problem is this i have a sorted array of ints and an array of structures called product.

Structure:

```
typedef struct product 
{
   int ident;/*idp of a product*/
   char desc[64]; /* string that describes a product eg. "bread" */
   int price;  /* price of the product*/
   int weight; /* weight of the product eg. 2kg */
   int quant; /* quantity of the product in stock */
   int state_prod;/*state of a product, if its 1 its in the system else is 0 and is not in the system*/
}product;
```

arrays:

```
product p1 = {0,"pao",2,2,200,1};
product p2 = {1,"ovos",1,1,100,1};
product p3 = {2,"iscas",3,3,300,1};
product p4 = {3,"bacon",2,5,400,1};
product p5 = {4,"abacate",2,6,500,1};

product system[5] = {p1,p2,p3,p4,p5};

int price[5] = {1,2,2,2,3};
```

What i want is to create an array of products in each products price matches the int in the price array and if the price is the same i want correspond it with the ident.

for example:

```
int price_og[5] = {2,1,3,2,2};

product system[5] = {p1,p2,p3,p4,p5};

//after sorting the pirce_og array i get

int new_price[5] = {1,2,2,2,3}

// What i want as a result is this

product new_system[5] = {p2,p1,p5,p4,p3};

//new_system is the array of products that match the prices of new_price
```

The problem is this function that im using that problably as simple error and i cant seem to know what it is

function:

```
void align_prod(product a[],int b[],product c[]){
int i = 0;
while (i<5)
{
    if ((a[i].price == b[i]) && (a[i].ident == i))
    {
        c[i] = a[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
}
```

Seriouly any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please explain how p5 comes before p4 in your example.

Comment: Yes, we need to know how to order them if multiple products have the next price in the list.  Also, if the price is not found is it just placed at the end of the new array?

Comment: ok i didnt want to complicate but basically i created an array with the prices of the products in the system and then i applied the couting sort into the price array creating a new array and with that array i want to match the prices creating the new_system array

Answer (score 0):

you want to find products with same price. which means there might be some times in which you will enter `else-statement` and you will and do `i++` ,which means you are skipping some elements of array `c`. use another counter for array `c` like:

```
void align_prod(product a[],int b[],product c[]){
int i = 0 , j = 0;
while (i<5)
{
    if ((a[i].price == b[i]) && (a[i].ident == i))
    {
        c[j] = a[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
}
```